# Making a custom function in Google Sheets, the code works outside of sheets but not in sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So I'm writing a custom function for Google sheets which is supposed to take a single row or cells, produce a 1 dimensional array and use that data to create a URL. This is basically so I can help my friends track the prices of an item in a video game.

I have ran the code in a javascript environment outside of Google Sheets and everything acted as expected. But when I put the code in the script editor, it runs with unexpected behavior. The range of cells will always be 1 row by 13 columns but some of the columns may be void so the script is supposed to truncate the array of values so that there are no empty indexes. Then it is supposed to insert a "." between each value as it is concatenated into a string to produce the final URL. For some reason it does not remove any values and the "." are ","s when the URL is created in the cell.

Here is the code:

```
function STONKLINK(prices, premrkt) {
  var webLink = "https://turnipprophet.io?prices=";
  var priceLink = "";

  for (i = (prices.length - 1); prices[i] == 0; i--){
    prices.pop();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    priceLink = (priceLink + prices[i] + ".") 
  }

  priceLink = priceLink.substring(0, priceLink.length - 1);

  if (premrkt == "N/A") {
    webLink = webLink + priceLink;
  } else if (premrkt == "Fluctuating") {
    webLink = webLink + priceLink + "&pattern=0";
  } else if (premrkt == "Small Spike") {
    webLink = webLink + priceLink + "&pattern=3";
  } else if (premrkt == "Large Spike") {
    webLink = webLink + priceLink + "&pattern=1";
  } else if (premrkt == "Decreasing") {
    webLink = webLink + priceLink + "&pattern=2";
  }
  return webLink;

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you so much.

EDIT: While I still do not understand why this is happening, and I would like to understand, I have added a simple work around. By adding this line of code

```
webLink = webLink.replace(/,/g, ".");
```

before the `return`, all the commas will be replaced with dots. Still, any insight into the problem will be much appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello @ShawJorgensen, how are you **using** the above function and which parameters are you passing to it? When I tested the above snippet with a range of values for the `prices` and N/A for the `premrkt`, everything works as expected. Cheers!

Comment: So In my sheet I'll have cell T5 `=STONKLINK(C5:O5,P5)` In cells C5 through O5 there will either be numbers or empty cells and in P5 there will be one of the 5 strings. That last part seems to be working fine. 

 My understanding was that the first parameter would accept a range of cells and pass a dimensional array (for my use it will always be a single row and 13 columns) to `prices`. 

Here is a link to view the spreadsheet. It is currently running the exact same code, no changes.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZjvLCrlwpnxVtqdx8YDG8mqK1hDzdsJi5io2vkc1X3o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ale13 I also just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to test it, I really appreciate any help. I'm going to keep working on it as well, but I'm getting frustrated because I feel like Google Sheets is applying settings or formatting that is causing the problem and I can't figure out if it is or how to change it.

Comment: @ale13 I just wanted to add that I've found a work around so my code is working but I still don't understand why this problem existed in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you store values in Spreadsheets, the values which have a `,` are considered to be `strings` whilst the ones which have a `.` will be considered to be `numbers`.

So for example, if you have these values stored in the `B` column:

[image: values in spreadsheet]

If you log the `typeof(val1)` and `typeof(val2)` (where `val1` and `val2` are the values stored in `B1` respectively `B2`), this is what you will get:

[image: logging the values]

So the issue you were encountering is due to this fact. The values you have stored in your sheet are numbers and when you try to build the `webLink` string they are converted into strings - therefore, the `.` for a number becomes `,`.

#### Reference

- [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)